# Japanese onomatopoeia for "Shuffle"

Tags: word-requests, onomatopoeia

As in like a shoe scraping across the floor or the ground?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#I'm not completely sure what 'shuffle' means.

- スッ, スッスッ can be used for sounds made by slippers moving on the floor. スッ is for one step; スッスッ is for multiple steps (strides)
- シャカシャカ may be used when the movement is quick.
- ズッ, ズッズッ for shoes on the ground (a dictionary tells this is for scuffing).
- ズルズル is a general one for dragging (oneself, in the walking context).

Probably not shuffling, but

- キュッ, キュッキュッ is typically for basketball players moving in a court (the sound the shoes make when stopping on the floor).